# What's the difference between these examples (* and &)?

Tags: c, pointers

I wanted to know what's the difference between these two versions of the main() code in C:

```
int main() {
   uint32_t a;
   f(&a);
}
```

and

```
int main() {
   uint32_t *a;
   f(a);
}
```

for a function

```
void f(uint32_t *pointer) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your first example, you pass a pointer to uninitialized variable `a`.  `f()` could store a value there, for instance, and `main()` would be able to use that value later.

In your second example, you pass an uninitialized pointer `a`.  `f()` can't do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 4):

In the first version you pass a pointer to an un-initialized variable to f().
Don't, unless f()'s task is to initialize the variable.

In the second version you pass an uninitialized pointer to function  f().
Don't.

Answer (score 2):

They are defining different types of variables, without initialization.

`uint32_t a;`  defines `uint32_t` variable on the stack and the function call will pass its address to the `f()` function.

`uint32_t *a;` defines a pointer on the stack and pass its value to the function. The pointer is not initialized, thus it could point to any block and any attempt to access that address will result into undefined behavior.

From the perspective of the `f()` function, it sees pointer values passed to it. In the first call, it can use that address, while in the second, it cannot.

Answer (score 2):

wee pointer questions!!!

Ok so you know that the function f needs to take a pointer which is exactly as it sounds an address to that actual location in memory. For the first example(f(&a)) you have to pass the address because it lives inside the stack and really isn't shared anywhere outside the life of the function. so when the function returns the memory is destroyed and no longer available. the value of the pointer is not passed just the pointer to the value is passed. which can cause problems because if you change that value then all the things that "point to it" are now changed.

Now for the second one you get the memory from the heap or where ever but that stores the address of the value not the actual value so you can manipulate it and return nothing and the value is still there.